# Where is Uncle Grimmly?

Tags: luigis-mansion

In Luigi's Mansion for the Nintendo Gamecube,  the lights to the entire mansion shut off after I approach the door to the left of the Balcony. Then, Professor E. Gadd calls me on the Game Boy Horror and tells me I should find Uncle Grimmly before turning on the lights. He also told me that Uncle Grimmly likes rooms with mirrors.

Umm... one problem. Almost every single room has mirrors in it! Where could Uncle Grimmly possibly be?

Answer (score 5):

I remember this game! Unfortunately I couldn't remember the puzzle so I had to Google it. Uncle Grimmly is in the **Wardrobe Room**:

[image: Luigi in the Wardrobe Room]